# How do I access a list in a map and loop through that list

Tags: java

How do I access a list inside a map of type `Map <String, Object>`?

```
public Map<String, Object> getListInsideMapObject(Long id, Date from) {

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<MappedList> conTime = new ArrayList<>();
    conTime = xxxRepository.findByxxx(id, from);

    Map<String, Object> map = xxxService.xxx(id);
    List<String> times = (List<String>) map.get("xxx");

    for (MappedList t : conTime) {
        int num = 0;
        Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
        res.put("x", "");
        res.put("status", null);

        for (Contraction c : con) {
            num++;
            res.put("status", "stat");
            res.put("x", new Date());
        }
    }

   res.put("y", num);

    mapList.add(res);

    result.put("mapList", mapList);
    result.put("mapListA", mapListA);
    result.put("mapListB", mapListB); 
    //etc

    return result;
}
```

I am trying to call this service (`getListInsideMapObject`) and access each list from this map and loop through each list. for example in class xxx i want to call getListInsideMapObject(Long id, Date from) as a service and access each list from the map

Comment: You could post a [mcve] to reduce the complexity of this code. From what I see, you just have a `List<Map>` so what is the problem

Comment: You already seem to have code that attempts to do what you're asking. Does it not work? If not, what error are you getting or what is the expected versus actual output? Whether or not your code attempts to do what you ask, can you post a [mcve] more clearly demonstrating the problem you're having?

Comment: what is `w`, what is `weak`. Why is your method called `getListInsideMapObject` but is actually building a map? you should be more clear.

Comment: @Leonardo Pina i have updated the source, thanks for the correction. The class on its own is ok, but i want to call this method from another class and access all the list inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want something like this:

```
public NewClass1() {
    // have an instance from the class that gives you the map
    ClassThatBuildsTheMap mapClass = new ClassThatBuildsTheMap();
    // get the map.  must provide id and date
    Map <String, Object> myMap = mapClass.getListInsideMapObject(id, date);
    // access the lists inside the map
    useListInsideAMap(myMap);
}

private void useListInsideAMap(Map<String, Object> map){
    // Prior to Java8:
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey(); // if you want to use the key
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if(value instanceof List){
            // I supose it is a list of sytrings
            List l = (List) value;
            for (Object item : l) {
                // Do something with the item from the list
            }
        }
    }

    // Java8:
    // loop through the map
    map.forEach((String key, Object value)->{
        // if you want to use key, just call key

        // checks if the value (Object) from the map is a list
        if(value instanceof List){
            List l = (List)value;
            // loop through the list
            l.forEach((Object item)->{
                // Do something with the item from the list
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your `Object` to `List`

```
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> mapList= new ArrayList<>();
result.put("1", mapList);
-------------------------------------------------------
List<Map<String, Object>> = (List<Map<String, Object>>)result.get("1")
```

Then, you can loop normally using for/foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `Optional` object to get your map value by key and check it before cast to needed type (to avoid `ClassCastException` issues) :

```
Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Map<String, Object>> result = Optional.ofNullable(someMap.get("id"))
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof List)
        .map(obj -> (List<Map<String, Object>>)obj)
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

In that case you will have empty `List` (if element missed or type is not a `List`) or expected `List` value.